# Is a person "under contract" or "contracted" to do something? 

Tags: vocabulary

Which is the better choice, and why?

Answer (score 5):

I generally hear "under contract" as an adjective and "contracted" as past-tense verb:

The person/organization performing the activity is "under contract" and the person/organization requesting the activity "contracted" to have it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "a network of doctors and hospitals under contract to provide services", or "the local authority will contract with a wide range of agencies to provide services".

Answer (score 0):

- "Person P is/was under contract with organisation O to do job J."
- "Organization O (has) contracted person P to do job J."

Which do you want to emphasize, the person who took the contract or the organisation that gave it out?